# How do i draw an arc/spline on an image and get the length?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, automatic-ref-counting, spline

I can draw a line using points, but i am not sure how to draw a curve.

This was my code:

```
clc;
clear all;
I = imread('im6f.jpg');
figure,imshow(I);

[x,y] = ginput(2);
```

Then I used the distance formula to get the length.

How can i do a curve?

Comment: A curve between 2 points???

Comment: Write a parametric equation that defines the curve, and then plot that curve. (In other words, I don't expect that you will find a ready solution for this, but it shouldn't be hard to do manually)

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/278048

Answer (score 2):

How about using `interp1` for interpolating a spline? Let's say `fold = 10` is the approximate increase in resolution you want. Then, `[x, y] = ginput()` without a specific upper limit of points. The number of points the user specified is `n = length(x)`. Then,

```
t = 1 : (1/fold) : n;
xi = interp1(1 : n, x, t, 'spline');
yi = interp1(1 : n, y, t, 'spline');
plot(xi, yi, 'linewidth', 3);
```

gives you the following, where the red blobs mark the points where I clicked. You have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to stop collecting coordinates.

[image]

`xi` and `yi` are `fold`-fold resampled coordinates of `x` and `y` using `'spline'` as the interpolation method. You could have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for other options.

```
dx = xi(1 : end-1) - xi(2 : end);
dy = yi(1 : end-1) - yi(2 : end);
d = sum(sqrt(dx.^2 + dy.^2));
```

`d` is roughly the length of that spline, calculated as the sum of the length of all edges. In the case shown above, `d = 118.97`.